# After update to 21.10, usb type-c displayport not work

Tags: usb, 21.10, displayport

After update to ubuntu 21.10, I can not connect to my usb type-c monitor

Comment: More information would be helpful.  What were you using before the update to 21.10?  What is the model of computer and monitor?  What have you tried already to resolve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found that I have change to another type-c line, and that line only support power supply. After change the line of type-c, it work again.